# DHCP stopping ethernet getting an IP address

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip, raspberry-pi-os-buster

So have an issue getting the Raspberry Pi 4 (running the new Buster image) from releasing my eth0 interface to get an IP. It works fine with the wifi, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

My router is setup to use the RPi as a Pihole/Unbound server and the router itself has all the MAC addresses (the RPi included) assigned to a static local IP successfully. I have noticed under ipconfig (below) there's no ivp4 address like there is for the wlan0?

I've tried setting the eth0 manually to no avail, and also 'sudo update-rc.d dhcpcd disable' but that makes both network interfaces unusable until I enable it. If I hover my mouse over the taskbar it says 'eth0 link up: configuring'. My settings are as follows and any advice would be appreciated:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet auto

iface wlan0 inet auto
```

And also:

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.

persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private

# Example static IP configuration:

profile static_eth0
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.101/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1
```

Ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::448:42ca:f2a6:a8e3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:a6:32:a4:33:f2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2071  bytes 168444 (164.4 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 27  bytes 3708 (3.6 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 8929  bytes 763858 (745.9 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 8929  bytes 763858 (745.9 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.146  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::eb8a:d19:4ffd:ddac  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:a6:32:a4:33:f3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 12449  bytes 2419180 (2.3 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 17279  bytes 5024832 (4.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` is obsolete (not to mention the errors). Try NORMAL Buster/Stretch settings. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: @Milliways Many thanks for the reply, I've had a look at that page and it only seems to mention the wifi connection? I can't see much at all on the eth0?

Comment: you can't see "much" ... what little you do see is all you need